# C - Reading from a file with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have to read from a file some numbers with 5 threads (every thread reads one number), synchronizing the access to the file itself. I wanted to know if the sequent ways to proceed so that threads share the mutex and the file pointer are equivalent:

1) declare mutex and file to read as global variables

```
#include <....>

pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
FILE *fp;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    fp=open_file(argv[1]);
}
```

and 2) define a data structure for the threads and then associate its field with the mutex and the file in the main function

```
#include <....>

struct data
{
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_mutex_t *ptmx;
   FILE *f;

  .....
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   FILE *fp=open_file(argv[1]);
   struct data td[5];
   pthread_mutex_t mtx;

   pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,NULL)

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      td[i].f=fp;
      td[i].ptmx=&mtx;
   }

   ....
}
```

i've reported only a piece of the code for simplicity, and supposed that the file is passed with line command.

Comment: Since you are working with command line arguments, you have to use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: yes, i know...i've not written the whole code! i just want to know if for the threads the codes i've shown are equivalent

Comment: I guess the core of the question is how to use the Lock to switch off between the 5 threads in a subsequent order?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use something like `lockf()`?

Comment: in the exercise is requested the use of a mutex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are completely equivalent.

In both cases, the threads have the mutex and `FILE` pointer visible, sharing the same values.